# displaying image from sqlite in django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-templates

I have a model that has a field of Image
`profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='clothes_images', null=True, blank=True)`.
I have a function that returns the image URL

```
def image_url(self):
        if self.profile_picture:
            return self.profile_picture.url
        return None
```

but when I display in my template using this code `<img src="{{cloth.image_url}}">`
I get this error `Not Found: /media/clothes_images/1_fSqDIIb.png`

my image name is 1.png but it changes when I store that and not find that.

I want to display each image that stores in my local system.
this is my setting.py file for media `MEDIA_URL = '/media/' MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` 
also I added this code to my urls.py file
`if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Can you show your media root in your settings, also is this for local development or production?

Comment: Check your MEDIA settings in project settings.py 
It should be something like this # settings.py

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Also, make sure if images are going to 'clothes_images' Directory. If it does then there is something wrong in your views.py image handling logic.

Provide more details.

Comment: are you rinning this with `DEBUG = False`?

Comment: no debug = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the image as `base64`  encoded into your database you can show it into html:

```
# pip install pybase64

import base64
with open("image.jpg", "rb") as imagefile:
    convert = base64.b64encode(imagefile.read())
print(convert.decode('utf-8'))

# in html page the tag for showing the image looks like
# <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG..." />
```

Comment: How could this answer is right? He uses Imagefield which is a path to actual image, not that image itself.